# Can hyperspectral Image(.raw) format convert to DNG? Will it be visible in Matlab?

Tags: raw, image-processing

Will it be visible in Matlab? Please suggest me for this. I want to open that images in Matlab??  Should I try to convert it to other format??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about image processing (likely for remote sensing) in a non-photographic context.

Answer (score 3):

I never used Matlab but here is the exhaustive list: [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

DNG is not in any way suited for hyperspectral images. I also suspect that the .raw files which you talk about have spectrum information and not just tristimulus information.

Added: I may guess that you talk about the photographs of a spectrum. In this case you may use [DcRaw](https://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) which exports perfectly unedited images to TIFF files (among others) and also supports almost any consumer camera ever produced.

Here is a command line which will probably fullfill your needs:
dcraw -4 -T -h -o 0 file.raw